# What was the judicial body in 16th century France called?

Tags: france, catholic-church, early-modern, protestant-church, paris

I was listening to a series of audio lectures on Religious wars in Europe. In the lecture on French wars of religion, there was a mention of a judicial authority in Paris.
However, I couldn't catch the name because the audio was unclear. However the name started with a 'P'. Can someone help me with its name so that I can know more about it?

Comment: Sounds like the [*Parlement of Paris*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlement)

Comment: Oh. I think the instructor used the French word for it, then. What is it called in French?

Comment: ...... *le parlement de Paris*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the [Ancien Régime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancien_R%C3%A9gime), the judiciary of France was divided into several local bodies known as [***parlements***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlement). Despite the similarity of their names to the modern parliamentary institution, the *Ancien Régime parlement* were quite different. They formed a powerful component of the French judicial system, serving as the highest courts of appeals for their region. They were also responsible for promulgating the King of France's laws within their jurisdiction - or refuse to do so. In this way they functioned as checks on absolutist royal power.

The most prestigious and famous of these was the ***Parlement of Paris***, created around A.D. 1260. This sounds like the judicial authority the lecture is talking about.